# Does my ship placement for a Battlefield game look stable? (Java)

Tags: java

This is my code to place ships for a game of Battleship:

```
    static void placeShips()
{
    Random r = new Random();

    int[] ships = {5, 4, 3, 3, 2};

    for(int i = 0; i < ships.length; i++)
    {
        int direction = r.nextInt(2);

        loop: switch(direction)
        {
        //Down
            case 0:
                int spot1 = r.nextInt(10 - (ships[i]+1));
                int spot2 = r.nextInt(10);

                for(int j = 0; j < ships[i]; j++)
                    if(boardArray[spot1 + j][spot2] != 0)
                    {
                        i--;
                        break loop;
                    }

                for(int j = 0; j < ships[i]; j++)
                    boardArray[spot1 + j][spot2] = 1;

            break;

        //Right
            case 1:
                spot1 = r.nextInt(10);
                spot2 = r.nextInt(10 - (ships[i]+1));

                for(int j = 0; j < ships[i]; j++)
                    if(boardArray[spot1][spot2 + j] != 0)
                    {
                        i--;
                        break loop;
                    }

                for(int j = 0; j < ships[i]; j++)
                    boardArray[spot1][spot2 + j] = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Does anybody know a reliable way of testing it? It isn't finished yet, but essentially the array is a 10x10 (of all 0s) and it uses this formula to place ships on an array, boardArray. It's a bit annoying to constantly rerun the program, is there a faster way to be 100% sure they won't overlap?

Normally I would just test it and turn it in if I don't see problems, but this game counts as my final so I want it to be as close to perfect as possible

Comment: Write some unit tests like all professionals do (?!). See junit. A good institution will mark you up simply for providing a test suite. By the way, I think break to a label is a poor programming construct. Avoid if you can.

Comment: [JUnit](http://junit.org) is the de-facto standard library for unit-testing.

Comment: And you'll want to inject your `Random` instance in order to make the tests repeatable (by providing a seeded instance in the tests).

Comment: [Misko Hevery](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/) has written some really good stuff about writing testable code. I suggest you read it.

Comment: It’s an aside: modifying your loop control variable, in this case `i`, inside your for loop makes for unreadable code. You are right in wanting to test it, but you also want your reader to be able to understand it and be convinced it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The most reliable way to test it is to write some [unit tests](http://junit.org/junit4/). Google has a mantra ["Debugging sucks, testing rocks"](https://www.flickr.com/photos/dullhunk/3712840085).

The most important change to make to your code to make it testable is to make it deterministic.

Fundamentally, the output of your code is determined by 2 things:

- The randoms generated by `r`;
- The initial values in `boardArray`.

If you can control both of these things, then your code should do exactly the same thing each time you run it. And that means that it does exactly the same thing each time you *test* it.

The easiest way to be able control these is to pass in both as method parameters:

```
static void placeShips(int[][] boardArray, Random r) {
  // Don't create r inside the method.

  // ... Rest of the method.
}
```

What this has done is to decouple the working of `placeShips` from the static state of the `static int[][] boardArray` you have somewhere, and from the non-determinism of creating the `Random` inside the method.

Now you're in a better shape: you can (and *should*) write JUnit tests; but you can now invoke `placeShip` from anywhere, e.g. a `main(String[])` method:

```
int[][] boardArray = new int[10][10];  // Guaranteed to be full of zeros.
Random r = new Random(0);  // Seeded with 0, so it always generates the same numbers.

placeShips(boardArray, r);

// Now check the contents of boardArray are what you expect.
```

You should actually split up the logic in `placeShips` to create "testing seams": it's currently quite a big method, and all you can test is that `boardArray` has specific elements in specific places. I'm not going to go into how to split it up, but it's something you should think about.